# Web Authentication: Can't Authenticate using fingerprint

Tags: android, android-fingerprint-api, webauthn, safetynet

I have implemented WebAuthn registration for android-safetynet. Where I can register using my fingerprint. However, I am not given an option to authenticate using a fingerprint.

What can be the reason behind this?

[This is the Object provided to navigator.credentials.create()](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wr3gw.png)

[This is the Object that is provided to navigator.credentials.get()](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RxikH.png)

Comment: Many things can go wrong. You need to share details, beginning with any error message you have.

Comment: There are no error messages, it is just not showing an option to use fingerprint to login. The only options offered are: USB, NFC and Bluetooth. I have added snaps of the objects I use to create and get credentials.

Comment: Please share your code in a safety manner, thus people can check what is wrong

Comment: @hatirlatici I would keep that in mind. For now, the core issue has been resolved by the mistake pointed out by mackie

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you confirm that `transportsList` is the actual name you're using inside your `PublicKeyCredentialDescriptor`? If so, that looks incorrect according to the spec which says it should be called `transports`:

https://www.w3.org/TR/webauthn/#credential-dictionary

I guess the Android implementation will always default to external transports unless you explicitly provide `transports: ["internal"]`

Comment: Oh yes, thanks for your keen eye. It is indeed working!